# CMake check that a local file exists

Tags: file, cmake, file-exists

In my CMake script I want to see if I have a file on my system, and if it is there do something with it, otherwise do something with a default file. Here is the code:

```
find_file(
          ${project_name}_${customer}_config 
          ${ROOT}/configuration/${customer}/configuration.${project_name}.xml
)

if(NOT ${${project_name}_${customer}_config} STREQUAL
   ${project_name}_${customer}_config-NOTFOUND )
        configure_file(${ROOT}/configuration/${customer}/configuration.${project_name}.xml
                       ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/conf/configuration.xml)
else()
    configure_file(${FAPP_ROOT}/configuration/Default/configuration.${project_name}.xml
                   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/conf/configuration.xml)
endif()
```

But it seems, this is not working.

What is the proper way of checking if a file exists in CMake?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

The proper way to check if a file exists, if you already know the full path name to the file is simply:

```
if(EXISTS "${ROOT}/configuration/${customer}/configuration.${project_name}.xml")
   ...
else()
   ...
endif()
```

Comment: [documentation is here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/if.html?highlight=EXISTS)

Comment: Unfortunally, `EXISTS` does not what it claims to do. If the checked file can't be read or written, it return false, although the file is visible. This is a sad bug, because this sometimes can be useful, like the existence of a certain device file.

Comment: oddly this simple command does not work for any file i create :/

Comment: Can you provide an example that does not work? Is there some sort of race condition where the file is possibly created shortly after you try to use the EXISTS test?

Comment: For the latest cmake (at least 3.14+) this is incomplete answer. You have to additionally test on not a directory path: `if (EXISTS "..." AND NOT IS_DIRECTORY "...")` as long as `EXISTS` returns true on directories too!

Comment: @Andry This is a valid point. It has been the case going back to at least CMake 3.0, `if (EXISTS "...")` will return true if the file OR directory exists. Here are the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/if.html).

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to just use

```
if(NOT ${project_name}_${customer}_config)
```

From the [docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#command%3aif):

> `if(<constant>)`
>
> True if the constant is 1, ON, YES, TRUE, Y, or a non-zero number. False if the constant is 0, OFF, NO, FALSE, N, IGNORE, "", or ends in the suffix '-NOTFOUND'.

However, if the file *is* found using [`find_file`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#command%3afind_file), the value is cached, and subsequent runs of CMake will not try to find it again.  To force a recheck on every run, before the `find_file` call do:

```
unset(${project_name}_${customer}_config CACHE)
```

Answer (score 8):

I believe the `if (EXISTS <path>)` is a good solution. I'd like to share a scenario I recently encountered, though you probably won't care about this scenario in most cases.

Please note, this solution will not return true if the file is not accessible by the effective user. The file does exist, but it's just not readable.

A workaround for this scenario if you do care about whether the file really exists or not, is to call `execute_process(COMMAND ls /dev/fb0 RESULT_VARIABLE result OUTPUT_QUIET ERROR_QUIET)` and then check the `result` like this:

```
if (result)
    message("/dev/fb0 doesn't exist.")
endif()
```

**edit**: add `ERROR_QUIET` in `execute_process` or you will get error messages from ls when the file does not exist.

Comment: Thank you! The workaround provided here is the only working solution in my case.

Answer (score 8):

From Condition Syntax [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/if.html):

> `if(EXISTS path-to-file-or-directory)`
>
> True if the named file or directory exists. **Behavior is well-defined only for full paths**. Resolves symbolic links, i.e. if the named file or directory is a symbolic link, returns true if the target of the symbolic link exists.

If the file you are looking for is located within the current cmakelist-file, then one solution could be:

`if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${FILE_WORKING_ON})`
...