# cmake: configure_file only if it does not exists

Tags: cmake

How can one generate the file only if it doesn't exists already?

`configure_file` will always touch target file and replace with user modified options.

Comment: Although @Frederich already gave you a perfect answer, I'd like to ask you what is the *real* problem you are trying to solve.  Checking for the existence of a file in order to configure it will eventually generate more problems than it solves.  Just think of scenario where you want to *re*configure file.

Comment: Essentially I just want to copy the empty config file to the application folder, and then user can update the file their own way.

Comment: In that case, `file(COPY)` may also be of interest. It checks modification time before copying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CMake check that a local file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067401/cmake-check-that-a-local-file-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the file already exists with a conditional statement like [if (EXISTS)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#exists) :

```cmake
if (NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${outfile}")
    configure_file(${infile} ${outfile})
endif()
```